# Is it possible to use mouseEnter with ember-bootstrap components?

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently using [Ember Bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) in a project and creating a Navigation Bar has been my first real experience of using contextual components.

The current code for the nav bar is as follows:

```
{{#bs-navbar type="dark" backgroundColor="primary" class="p-0" as |navbar|}}
{{navbar.toggle}}
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;height:50px ">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-left">
        {{#navbar.content}}
        {{#navbar.nav as |nav|}}

        {{#nav.dropdown as |dd|}}
        {{#dd.toggle}}Dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span>{{/dd.toggle}}
        {{#dd.menu as |ddm|}}
        {{#ddm.item}}{{#ddm.link-to "test1"}}Link 1{{/ddm.link-to}}{{/ddm.item}}
        {{#ddm.item}}{{#ddm.link-to "test2"}}Link 2{{/ddm.link-to}}{{/ddm.item}}
        {{/dd.menu}}
        {{/nav.dropdown}}

        {{#nav.item}}
        {{#nav.link-to "test"}}Current User: <b>MICKEY MOUSE</b>{{/nav.link-to}}
        {{/nav.item}}
        {{/navbar.nav}}
        {{/navbar.content}}
    </div>
</div>
{{/bs-navbar}}
```

Part of the specification for this component is that a sub-menu appears to the left when a user hovers over one of the dropdown links and I'm having a hard time working out how to do it.

The main problem is I can't work out how to take advantage of the `mouseEnter` event in a contextual component like this. Where I could normally add an action in element space like:

```
<h1 {{action "anAction" on="mouseEnter"}}>Text</h1>
```

I'm unable to do so here because the element space is controlled by the sub-components. Likewise, If I try and use a closure action like

```
{{ddm.link-to anAction=(action 'hostAction')}}
```

Then I am unsure how to specify the action fire on the `mouseEnter` event and get errors of an 'action not found' nature - I suspect because the Ember Bootstrap add on does not expose a `anAction` action for me to use.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

( I did try to set up a working twiddle for this but was unable to do anything except show an empty navigation bar with no links!)

Comment: Not an answer so much as a referral, but there was a lot of discussion about this problem and possible solutions on the EmberMap podcast at https://embermap.com/podcast/a-dropdown-nest I think they may have produced and in-depth video as well.

Comment: Thanks for the referral, that was super interesting and they did in fact do a video that I'll definitely check out

Comment: Hi @Abuelo could you please upvote my answer if it is helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can trigger an action in ember hbs using `onmouseenter`

```
<h1 onmouseenter={{action "action-name"}}>Text</h1>
```

use `mouseEnter` (which is similar to HTML `onmouseenter`) in your `{{#ddm.link-to}}`

```
{{#ddm.link-to mouseEnter=(action "action-name") "test1"}}Link 1{{/ddm.link-to}}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming the syntax - I can see where I was going wrong. I think you have answered the specific question but would you mind changing `onmouseover` to `mouseEnter` so I can accept the answer? `onmouseover` isn't one of the built in [Ember Events](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/)  and didn't give a result when implemented.

Comment: @Abuelo have correct as per your request. Could you please accept the answer ?
BTW you need to call an action on mouse hover, isn't it ?

Comment: `mouseEnter` will only work on ember components not on HTML tags. You must use `{{action}}` modifier or set action to `onmouseenter` property. `<h1 onmouseenter={{action "foo"}}>` or `<h1 {{action "foo" on="mouseEnter"}}>`. I would recommend the first one cause action modifier has some strange edge cases when it comes to bubbling.

Comment: that was my previous answer. since @Abuelo requested to change it to `mouseEnter` event, I blindly replaced at both places. HTML tags support `onmouseenter`

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!